# TFS URL from multiple connections

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a powershell script which deploys multiple procedures from TFS onto Databases directly. The current script connects to single TFS Url (hard coded in the script). Now I am trying to update the script to be ale to connect to multiple TFS depending on where the script resides and be able to deploy the procedures. Are there any commands that i can use to be able to do the same instead of using multiple if-else statements and asking the users to enter the url? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean something like a switch case?

Comment: Switch is more like if-else. i was wondering if there was some TFS command that will pick the server name automatically (from manage connections) depending on the projectname.

Comment: the collection name it's the same in all TFS url's?

Comment: Shayki - There are multiple collection hence i need a way to move between them without affecting my workspace currently i have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TeamProjectPicker` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff733628(v%3Dvs.120)), it provides a dialog to select a collection of TeamFoundation projects.

```
#$visualStudiopath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer'

$visualStudiopath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer'
Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
Add-type -path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll"

$picker = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamProjectPicker([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamProjectPickerMode]::NoProject,$false)
$dialogResult = $picker.ShowDialog()
$tfs = $picker.SelectedTeamProjectCollection
```

[image]